# Looking for a quote by Raistlin Majere

Tags: quotes, dragonlance

I am looking for a quote, possibly by Raistlin Majere of Dragonlance series. I saw it on a Chinese forum with Chinese text and I couldn't find the exact quote anywhere in the book.

Quote in Chinese text Translated:
"If you believe love is a kind of strength, not a weakness, prove it to me!" - Raistlin Majere

I looked in the book but couldn't find it. Maybe it's in the other book of Dragonlance series? Anyone has a clue?

Comment: I think I found a reference to the quote... "The second quote on the bottom of my post. I always felt sympathy for both of the twins when Raistlin said those words to Caramon in LotT. Sympathy for Raistlin because though he had endured and attained so very much to become the greatest wizard of his Age, but he didn't understand the power of love..."

Comment: "... At least at that point, anyway. I felt sympathy for Caramon because he finally saw his brother clearly for what Raistlin was and still accepted him, making one more attempt to help Raistlin, out of love. And was rejected. That scene with that quote still evokes emotion in me when I re-read it." (http://www.dragonlanceforums.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-4237.html)

Comment: Sometimes a link to your source, even if it's a Chinese forum may be helpful. For example I did find the quote on the following site: https://lanyumo.wordpress.com/2007/03/11/show%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%8B%E6%9C%80%E7%88%B1%E7%9A%84%E5%A5%87%E5%B9%BB%E5%90%8D%E8%A8%80/ and it points to this quote being said by Raistlin to Palin (assumable Palin Majere). If this is the same origin to your quote then it would have to be found in the Second Generations novellas, likely in The Legacy.

Comment: @S.Fruggiero Spot on! The link you provided contained fantasy quotes from another site and it's where my quote came from at the first place. Here is the exact Chinese version :"“如果你相信爱是一种力量，而不是软弱的表现的话，证明给我看！”". At the moment, I don't have access to the original page ( obviously the site was refactored ). Do you have any idea where did the quote came from?

Answer (score 9):

Is this what you're looking for?

> "Enough of this nonsense," Dougan growled. "To my mind, the young one handled himself well enough, Master Mage, considering his age and inexperience. And if he was a wee bit distracted by his love for the lass, it was her love that saved him in the end. **Where would you be now, Raistlin Majere, if you had considered love a strength, not a weakness?**"
> "Probably sitting in my brothers kitchen, making gold coins come out of my nose for the enjoyment of little children," Raistlin retorted.
>
> <sub>-- Raistlin Majere & Dougan Redhammer (Reorx), *Dragons of Summer Flame*</sub>

I found it on [this forum thread](http://raistlandforum.yuku.com/topic/392/Question-of-the-Month-Favorite-Scenes-and-Quotes#.Vtos0ubRjiw), which I found in turn by searching Google for "Raistlin Majere quote love strength weakness".

Comment: Thank you. I have seen this in the book. However, the text does not have matching meaning/expression. I doubt it's the one.

Comment: I just checked the Chinese version of "Dragons of Summer Flame" and yours is the only one matching the quote. I think the person who wrote the quote might have interpreted this quote with his own text. Or else the quote is in another book.

Comment: Nice find. I would have assumed it'd be found in *Tales III, Raistlin's Daughter.*